# How many paths of length $n$ with the same start and end point can be found on a hexagonal grid?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, permutations, random-walk

Given [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150399/finding-all-possible-paths-of-n-length-in-hexagonal-grid?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), what about the special case when the start point and end point are the same? I ask it here instead because I am looking for the mathematical solution to counting these *different* paths.

Another change in my case is that we must move at every step. How many such *different* paths can be found and what would be the most efficient approach? I guess this would be a random walk of some sort?

My thinking so far is, since we must always return to our starting point, thinking about $n/2$ might be easier. Then at every step, except at step $n/2$, we have 6 choices to move. At $n/2$ we have a different amount of choices depending on if $n$ is even or odd. We also have a different amount of choices depending on where we are (what previous choices we made). For example if $n$ is even and we went straight out, we only have one choice at $n/2$, going back. But if $n$ is even and we didn't go straight out, we have more choices.

It is all the cases at this turning point that I have trouble getting straight.

Am I on the right track?

To be clear, I just want to count the paths. So I guess we are looking for some conditioned permutation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each step is in one of the six directions 0º, 60º, 120º, 180º, 240º, 300º. Let $n_i$ be the number of steps in the direction $60i$ degrees. You can show that a path will return to its start if and only if
$$
n_0-n_3 =n_2-n_5=n_4-n_1\tag1
$$ 
Of the $6^n$ possible walks, you must count the number of walks which satisfy the above condition. The following sum which computes this:
$$
\sum_{k=-\lfloor{n/3}\rfloor}^{\lfloor{n/3}\rfloor}\sum_{a+b+c=n}\binom{n}{a,b,c}\binom{a}{\frac{k+a}{2}}\binom{b}{\frac{k+b}{2}}\binom{c}{\frac{k+c}{2}}
$$
The above is correct as long as you use the convention that $\binom{m}{i}$ is zero whenever $i$ is not a nonnegative integer. Essentially, $a$ corresponds to $n_0+n_3$, $b$ to $n_2+n_5$ and $c$ to $n_0+n_3$, while $k$ is the common value of $(1)$.

**Edit:** Another way to express the above summation is 
$$
\sum_{k=-\lfloor{n/3}\rfloor}^{\lfloor{n/3}\rfloor}\sum_{a=0}^n\sum_{b=0}^{n-a}\binom{n}{a,b,c}\binom{a}{\frac{k+a}{2}}\binom{b}{\frac{k+b}{2}}\binom{n-a-b}{\frac{k+n-a-b}{2}}
$$

Comment: Good answer! I just have trouble interpreting the sum notations. Are non-integer $k$ fine? And the second sum, from and to what does it sum? Sorry, I have not used anything but the standard sum notation $\sum_{i=0}^{n}x_i$. An explanation of these sums and the answer would be complete to me. Thanks!

Comment: Good question, my notation was very unclear. k has to be an integer, so it the bounds should be n/3 rounded down. For the second sum, what it means is that you enumerate all choices of three nonnegative integers a,b,c which satisfy a+b+c=0, and add up the inside function applied to all of them. I can edit in a better explanation later

Comment: Alright, thanks! Now I get it. Yes, please edit and I will accept your answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Spoke too quickly, your comment says $a+b+c=0$, but the sum in your answer says $a+b+c=n$, which one is it?

Comment: Whoops, I meant a+b+c=n

Comment: Comparing this to a dynamic programming solution, it seems that for $n>4$ all even $n$ return more paths than the "correct" dynamic programming solution. This is the honeycomb walk programming problem, the last one here: https://ncpc.idi.ntnu.no/ncpc2006/ncpc2006problems.pdf
Here is one solution from GitHub: https://github.com/mbobesic/algorithms-playground/blob/master/kattis/HoneycombWalk.java

I could have made some mistake somewhere of course. But I have triple checked my work.